# What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, abi

`int 0x80` on Linux always invokes the 32-bit ABI, regardless of what mode it's called from:  args in `ebx`, `ecx`, ... and syscall numbers from `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`.   (Or crashes on 64-bit kernels compiled without `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`).

**64-bit code should use `syscall`**, with call numbers from `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`, and args in `rdi`, `rsi`, etc.  See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64).  If your question was marked a duplicate of this, **see that link for details on how you *should* make system calls in 32 or 64-bit code.**  If you want to understand what exactly happened, keep reading.

(For an example of 32-bit vs. 64-bit `sys_write`, see [Using interrupt 0x80 on 64-bit Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503944/using-interrupt-0x80-on-64-bit-linux))

---

`syscall` system calls are faster than `int 0x80` system calls, so use native 64-bit `syscall` unless you're writing polyglot machine code that runs the same when executed as 32 or 64 bit.  (`sysenter` always returns in 32-bit mode, so it's not useful from 64-bit userspace, although it is a valid x86-64 instruction.)

Related: [**The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls** (on x86)](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/) for how to make `int 0x80` or `sysenter` 32-bit system calls, or `syscall` 64-bit system calls, or calling the vDSO for "virtual" system calls like `gettimeofday`.  Plus background on what system calls are all about.

---

Using `int 0x80` makes it possible to write something that will assemble in 32 or 64-bit mode, so it's handy for an `exit_group()` at the end of a microbenchmark or something.

Current PDFs of the official i386 and x86-64 System V psABI documents that standardize function and syscall calling conventions are linked from https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for beginner guides, x86 manuals, official documentation, and performance optimization guides / resources.

---

But since people keep posting questions with code that uses [`int 0x80` in 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033028/sys-read-syscall-vs-int-0x80-in-gnu-assembler), or accidentally [building 64-bit binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain) from source written for 32-bit, I wonder **what *exactly* does happen on current Linux?**

**Does `int 0x80` save/restore all the 64-bit registers?  Does it truncate any registers to 32-bit?  What happens if you pass pointer args that have non-zero upper halves?**

**Does it work if you pass it 32-bit pointers?**

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Clobbering r8-r11 is the least important reason!  #1 is: only supports 32-bit args / return values.  #2 is: strace decodes it wrong, so it's hard to debug.  #3 is: low performance.  #4 is: register args don't match x86-64 function-calling, and it uses `ebx` which is call-preserved.  (Rankings vary by use-case / beginner or not, but I think those all outweigh clearing r8-r11 all the time.)  Anyway, I'll think about a better intro.

Comment: I don't use x86 assembly, but I bookmarked this question as an interesting example of how to write an artificial canonical.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Thanks.  This one was tricky to write because there's so much different info to impart, and multiple layers of the onion to peel back.  (And quite a few moving parts, like debugging tools like `strace` interacting with it, and kernel support).  I ended up making the question itself start with the practical advice of what to actually do, and phrased the question as a "why not" / "what happens if".  That could work well for similar topics.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**TL:DR**: `int 0x80` works when used correctly, as long as any pointers fit in 32 bits (**stack pointers don't fit**).  But beware that **`strace` decodes it wrong** unless you have a very recent strace + kernel.

`int 0x80` zeros r8-r11 [for reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505049/using-r8-register-as-a-loop-counter-results-in-endless-loop-why/38520761#38520761), and preserves everything else.  Use it exactly like you would in 32-bit code, with the 32-bit call numbers.  (Or better, don't use it!)

Not all systems even support `int 0x80`:  The Windows Subsystem for Linux version 1 (WSL1) is strictly 64-bit only: [`int 0x80` doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736104/assembly-compiled-executable-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-doesnt-produce-output).  It's also possible to build Linux kernels [without IA-32 emulation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMD64/FAQ#What_kernel_should_I_use.3F) either.  (No support for 32-bit executables, no support for 32-bit system calls).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300194/does-wsl-2-really-support-32-bit-program) re: making sure your WSL is actually WSL2 (which uses an actual Linux kernel in a VM.)

---

#### The details: what's saved/restored, which parts of which regs the kernel uses

`int 0x80` uses `eax` (not the full `rax`) as the system-call number, dispatching to the same table of function-pointers that 32-bit user-space `int 0x80` uses.  (These pointers are to `sys_whatever` implementations or wrappers for the native 64-bit implementation inside the kernel.  System calls are really function calls across the user/kernel boundary.)

Only the low 32 bits of arg registers are passed.  **The upper halves of `rbx`-`rbp` are preserved, but ignored by `int 0x80` system calls.**  Note that passing a bad pointer to a system call doesn't result in SIGSEGV; instead the system call returns `-EFAULT`.  If you don't check error return values (with a debugger or tracing tool), it will appear to silently fail.

All registers (except eax of course) are saved/restored (including RFLAGS, and the upper 32 of integer regs), except that **r8-r11 are zeroed**.  `r12-r15` are call-preserved in the x86-64 SysV ABI's function calling convention, so the registers that get zeroed by `int 0x80` in 64-bit are the call-clobbered subset of the "new" registers that AMD64 added.

This behaviour has been preserved over some internal changes to how register-saving was implemented inside the kernel, and comments in the kernel mention that it's usable from 64-bit, so this ABI is probably stable.  (I.e. you can count on r8-r11 being zeroed, and everything else being preserved.)

The return value is sign-extended to fill 64-bit `rax`.  [(Linux declares 32-bit sys_ functions as returning signed `long`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/89c9fea3c8034cdb2fd745f551cde0b507fd6893/arch/x86/entry/syscall_32.c#L9).)  This means that pointer return values (like from `void *mmap()`) need to be zero-extended before use in 64-bit addressing modes

Unlike `sysenter`, it preserves the original value of `cs`, so it returns to user-space in the same mode that it was called in.  (Using `sysenter` results in the kernel setting `cs` to `$__USER32_CS`, which selects a descriptor for a 32-bit code segment.)

---

**Older `strace` decodes `int 0x80` incorrectly** for 64-bit processes.  It decodes as if the process had used `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500362/running-32-bit-assembly-code-on-a-64-bit-linux-64-bit-processor-explain-the/46020177#46020177) can be [very confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8106176/224132).  e.g. `strace` prints `write(0, NULL, 12 <unfinished ... exit status 1>` for `eax=1` / `int $0x80`, which is actually `_exit(ebx)`, not `write(rdi, rsi, rdx)`.

I don't know the exact version where the `PTRACE_GET_SYSCALL_INFO` feature was added, but Linux kernel 5.5 / strace 5.5 handle it.  It misleadingly says the process "runs in 32-bit mode" but does decode correctly.  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456266/can-ptrace-tell-if-an-x86-system-call-used-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-abi)).

---

**`int 0x80` works as long as all arguments (including pointers) fit in the low 32 of a register**.  This is the case for static code and data in the default code model ("small") [in the x86-64 SysV ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).  (Section 3.5.1
: *all symbols are known to be located in the virtual addresses in the range `0x00000000` to `0x7effffff`*, so you can do stuff like `mov edi, hello` (AT&T `mov $hello, %edi`) to get a pointer into a register with a 5 byte instruction).

But **this is *not* the case for [position-independent executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables), which many Linux distros now configure `gcc` to make by default** (and they [enable ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) for executables).  For example, I compiled a `hello.c` on Arch Linux, and set a breakpoint at the start of main.  The string constant passed to `puts` was at `0x555555554724`, so a 32-bit ABI `write` system call would not work.  (GDB disables ASLR by default, so you always see the same address from run to run, if you run from within GDB.)

Linux puts the stack near [the "gap" between the upper and lower ranges of canonical addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977755/address-canonical-form-and-pointer-arithmetic/38983032#38983032), i.e. with the top of the stack at 2^48-1.  (Or somewhere random, with ASLR enabled).  So `rsp` on entry to `_start` in a typical statically-linked executable is something like `0x7fffffffe550`, depending on size of env vars and args.  Truncating this pointer to `esp` does not point to any valid memory, so system calls with pointer inputs will typically return `-EFAULT` if you try to pass a truncated stack pointer.  (And your program will crash if you truncate `rsp` to `esp` and then do anything with the stack, e.g. if you built 32-bit asm source as a 64-bit executable.)

---

#### How it works in the kernel:

In the Linux source code, `arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S` defines
`ENTRY(entry_INT80_compat)`.  Both 32 and 64-bit processes use the same entry point when they execute `int 0x80`.

`entry_64.S` is defines native entry points for a 64-bit kernel, which includes interrupt / fault handlers and `syscall` native system calls from [long mode (aka 64-bit mode)](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64#Long_Mode) processes.

`entry_64_compat.S` defines system-call entry-points from compat mode into a 64-bit kernel, plus the special case of `int 0x80` in a 64-bit process.   (`sysenter` in a 64-bit process may go to that entry point as well, but it pushes `$__USER32_CS`, so it will always return in 32-bit mode.)  There's a 32-bit version of the `syscall` instruction, supported on AMD CPUs, and Linux supports it too for fast 32-bit system calls from 32-bit processes.

I guess a **possible use-case** for `int 0x80` in 64-bit mode is if you wanted to use [a **custom code-segment descriptor**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355668/224132) that you installed with `modify_ldt`.  `int 0x80` pushes segment registers itself for use with [`iret`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IRET:IRETD.html), and Linux always returns from `int 0x80` system calls via `iret`.  The 64-bit `syscall` entry point sets `pt_regs->cs` and `->ss` to constants, `__USER_CS` and `__USER_DS`.  (It's normal that SS and DS use the same segment descriptors.  Permission differences are done with paging, not segmentation.)

`entry_32.S` defines entry points into a 32-bit kernel, and is not involved at all.

> The `int 0x80` entry point in [Linux 4.12's `entry_64_compat.S`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L267):
>
> ```
> /*
>  * 32-bit legacy system call entry.
>  *
>  * 32-bit x86 Linux system calls traditionally used the INT $0x80
>  * instruction.  INT $0x80 lands here.
>  *
>  * This entry point can be used by 32-bit and 64-bit programs to perform
>  * 32-bit system calls.  Instances of INT $0x80 can be found inline in
>  * various programs and libraries.  It is also used by the vDSO's
>  * __kernel_vsyscall fallback for hardware that doesn't support a faster
>  * entry method.  Restarted 32-bit system calls also fall back to INT
>  * $0x80 regardless of what instruction was originally used to do the
>  * system call.
>  *
>  * This is considered a slow path.  It is not used by most libc
>  * implementations on modern hardware except during process startup.
>  ...
>  */
>  ENTRY(entry_INT80_compat)
>  ...  (see the github URL for the full source)
> ```

The code zero-extends eax into rax, then pushes all the registers onto the kernel stack to form a [`struct pt_regs`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/80cee03bf1d626db0278271b505d7f5febb37bba/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h#L53).  This is where it will restore from when the system call returns.  It's in a standard layout for saved user-space registers (for any entry point), so `ptrace` from other process (like gdb or `strace`) will read and/or write that memory if they use `ptrace` while this process is inside a system call.  (`ptrace` modification of registers is one thing that makes return paths complicated for the other entry points.  See comments.)

But it pushes `$0` instead of r8/r9/r10/r11.   (`sysenter` and AMD `syscall32` entry points store zeros for r8-r15.)

I think this zeroing of r8-r11 is to match historical behaviour.  Before the [Set up full pt_regs for all compat syscalls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8169aff611956ed360e3313e8c718f530f58f6cb) commit, the entry point only saved the C call-clobbered registers.  It dispatched directly from asm with `call  *ia32_sys_call_table(, %rax, 8)`, and those functions follow the calling convention, so they preserve `rbx`, `rbp`, `rsp`, and `r12-r15`.  Zeroing `r8-r11` instead of leaving them undefined was [to avoid info leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505049/using-r8-register-as-a-loop-counter-results-in-endless-loop-why/38520761#38520761) from a 64-bit kernel to 32-bit user-space (which could far jmp to a 64-bit code segment to read anything the kernel left there).

The current implementation (Linux 4.12) dispatches 32-bit-ABI system calls from C, reloading the saved `ebx`, `ecx`, etc. from `pt_regs`.  (64-bit native system calls dispatch directly from asm, [with only a `mov %r10, %rcx`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L195) needed to account for the small difference in calling convention between functions and `syscall`.  Unfortunately it can't always use `sysret`, because CPU bugs make it unsafe with non-canonical addresses.  It does try to, so the fast-path is pretty damn fast, although `syscall` itself still takes tens of cycles.)

Anyway, in current Linux, 32-bit syscalls (including `int 0x80` from 64-bit) eventually end up in[`do_syscall_32_irqs_on(struct pt_regs *regs)`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/89c9fea3c8034cdb2fd745f551cde0b507fd6893/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L319).  It dispatches to a function pointer `ia32_sys_call_table`, with 6 zero-extended args.  This maybe avoids needing a wrapper around the 64-bit native syscall function in more cases to preserve that behaviour, so more of the `ia32` table entries can be the native system call implementation directly.

> [Linux 4.12 `arch/x86/entry/common.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/89c9fea3c8034cdb2fd745f551cde0b507fd6893/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L319)
>
> ```
> if (likely(nr < IA32_NR_syscalls)) {
>   /*
>    * It's possible that a 32-bit syscall implementation
>    * takes a 64-bit parameter but nonetheless assumes that
>    * the high bits are zero.  Make sure we zero-extend all
>    * of the args.
>    */
>   regs->ax = ia32_sys_call_table[nr](
>       (unsigned int)regs->bx, (unsigned int)regs->cx,
>       (unsigned int)regs->dx, (unsigned int)regs->si,
>       (unsigned int)regs->di, (unsigned int)regs->bp);
> }
>
> syscall_return_slowpath(regs);
> ```

In older versions of Linux that dispatch 32-bit system calls from asm (like 64-bit still did until 4.15<sup>1</sup>), the int80 entry point itself puts args in the right registers with `mov` and `xchg` instructions, using 32-bit registers.  It even uses `mov %edx,%edx` to zero-extend EDX into RDX (because arg3 happen to use the same register in both conventions).  [code here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b611acf4736b5b00c89dcc238f640337832abcb4/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L552).  This code is duplicated in the `sysenter` and `syscall32` entry points.

Footnote 1: Linux 4.15 (I think) introduced Spectre / Meltdown mitigations, and a major revamp of the entry points that made them them a trampoline for the meltdown case.  It also sanitized the incoming registers to avoid user-space values other than actual args being in registers during the call (when some Spectre gadget might run), by storing them, zeroing everything, then calling to a C wrapper that reloads just the right widths of args from the struct saved on entry.

I'm planning to leave this answer describing the much simpler mechanism because the conceptually useful part here is that the kernel side of a syscall involves using EAX or RAX as an index into a table of function pointers, with other incoming register values copied going to the places where the calling convention wants args to go.  i.e. `syscall` is just a way to make a call into the kernel, to its dispatch code.

---

#### Simple example / test program:

I wrote a simple Hello World (in NASM syntax) which sets all registers to have non-zero upper halves, then makes two `write()` system calls with `int 0x80`, one with a pointer to a string in `.rodata` (succeeds), the second with a pointer to the stack (fails with `-EFAULT`).

Then it uses the native 64-bit `syscall` ABI to `write()` the chars from the stack (64-bit pointer), and again to exit.

So all of these examples are using the ABIs correctly, except for the 2nd `int 0x80` which tries to pass a 64-bit pointer and has it truncated.

If you built it as a position-independent executable, the first one would fail too.  (You'd have to use a RIP-relative `lea` instead of `mov` to get the address of `hello:` into a register.)

I used gdb, but use whatever debugger you prefer.  Use one that highlights changed registers since the last single-step.  [`gdbgui`](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui) works well for debugging asm source, but is not great for disassembly.  Still, it does have a register pane that works well for integer regs at least, and it worked great on this example.

**See the inline `;;;` comments describing how register are changed by system calls**

```
global _start
_start:
    mov  rax, 0x123456789abcdef
    mov  rbx, rax
    mov  rcx, rax
    mov  rdx, rax
    mov  rsi, rax
    mov  rdi, rax
    mov  rbp, rax
    mov  r8, rax
    mov  r9, rax
    mov  r10, rax
    mov  r11, rax
    mov  r12, rax
    mov  r13, rax
    mov  r14, rax
    mov  r15, rax

    ;; 32-bit ABI
    mov  rax, 0xffffffff00000004          ; high garbage + __NR_write (unistd_32.h)
    mov  rbx, 0xffffffff00000001          ; high garbage + fd=1
    mov  rcx, 0xffffffff00000000 + .hello
    mov  rdx, 0xffffffff00000000 + .hellolen
    ;std
after_setup:       ; set a breakpoint here
    int  0x80                   ; write(1, hello, hellolen);   32-bit ABI
    ;; succeeds, writing to stdout
;;; changes to registers:   r8-r11 = 0.  rax=14 = return value

    ; ebx still = 1 = STDOUT_FILENO
    push 'bye' + (0xa<<(3*8))
    mov  rcx, rsp               ; rcx = 64-bit pointer that won't work if truncated
    mov  edx, 4
    mov  eax, 4                 ; __NR_write (unistd_32.h)
    int  0x80                   ; write(ebx=1, ecx=truncated pointer,  edx=4);  32-bit
    ;; fails, nothing printed
;;; changes to registers: rax=-14 = -EFAULT  (from /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h)

    mov  r10, rax               ; save return value as exit status
    mov  r8, r15
    mov  r9, r15
    mov  r11, r15               ; make these regs non-zero again

    ;; 64-bit ABI
    mov  eax, 1                 ; __NR_write (unistd_64.h)
    mov  edi, 1
    mov  rsi, rsp
    mov  edx, 4
    syscall                     ; write(edi=1, rsi='bye\n' on the stack,  rdx=4);  64-bit
    ;; succeeds: writes to stdout and returns 4 in rax
;;; changes to registers: rax=4 = length return value
;;; rcx = 0x400112 = RIP.   r11 = 0x302 = eflags with an extra bit set.
;;; (This is not a coincidence, it's how sysret works.  But don't depend on it, since iret could leave something else)

    mov  edi, r10d
    ;xor  edi,edi
    mov  eax, 60                ; __NR_exit (unistd_64.h)
    syscall                     ; _exit(edi = first int 0x80 result);  64-bit
    ;; succeeds, exit status = low byte of first int 0x80 result = 14

section .rodata
_start.hello:    db "Hello World!", 0xa, 0
_start.hellolen  equ   $ - _start.hello
```

[Build it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain) into a 64-bit static binary with

```
yasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 abi32-from-64.asm
ld -o abi32-from-64 abi32-from-64.o
```

Run `gdb ./abi32-from-64`.  In `gdb`, run `set disassembly-flavor intel` and `layout reg` if you don't have that in your `~/.gdbinit` already.  (GAS `.intel_syntax` is like MASM, not NASM, but they're close enough that it's easy to read if you like NASM syntax.)

```
(gdb)  set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb)  layout reg
(gdb)  b  after_setup
(gdb)  r
(gdb)  si                     # step instruction
    press return to repeat the last command, keep stepping
```

Press control-L when gdb's TUI mode gets messed up.  This happens easily, even when programs don't print to stdout themselves.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500362/running-32-bit-assembly-code-on-a-64-bit-linux-64-bit-processor-explain-the), which asks for an explanation of what was going on in 64-bit mode, after getting answers that say to build in 32-bit mode.  (Wrong syscall numbers and wrong `strace` decoding led to very confusing results).  Anyway, that got me curious and made me want to write up a canonical answer.

Comment: Does the `sysenter` behavior mean I can write a program that starts out as a 64 bit process and turns into a 32 bit process at runtime? That seems insane and dangerous.

Comment: If this is going to be the definitive work on the subject, I'll mention that I ran into a int 80/syscall issue related to [stack variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346514/2189500) a few years ago.  Might be something there worth mentioning here.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, insane and dangerous (for your process, not the system).   You can already do that without the kernel's help, with a far `jmp` using the known value of the kernel's segment selectors (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467092/inline-64bit-assembly-in-32bit-gcc-c-program#comment56677286_34467109).  AFAIK it's not useful, or supported under Linux, but you can do it.  There's even a `modify_ldt` system call that lets you do it in a "standard" way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355668/224132

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: good point, worth mentioning stack addresses in the TL:DR.  I mention stack pointers after the bolded section about position-independent executables (which put static code/data above 4GB as well), but that ended up about a page down by the time I was done writing >.<  Makes it hard to summarize in a TL:DR without saying anything that's not true in the general case.

Comment: @EOF: Just realized that a custom CS segment descriptor provides a use-case for `int 0x80`: it always saves/restores CS and SS, because Linux always returns from `int 0x80` via `iret`.  But `syscall` (in 64-bit mode) would end up setting `CS` back to its default `__USER_CS` value.

Comment: The zeroing of `r8-r11` I don't believe is guaranteed on old unpatched kernels. Seem to recall that this was part of a data bleed vulnerability at one time when you had a 32-bit program do an `int 0x80` and then switched to 64-bit code and gained access to the previous values of those registers.I think their fix was to zero them out prior to returning. You sort of mention it in the answer, but I believe you'll find a an actual vulnerability associated with it if you search.

Comment: Ah I finally found the [security issue](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/10/1/164)  . There is a writeup [here](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2009/10/04/linux-kernel-x86-64-register-leak) . And some code that [demonstrated](https://grsecurity.net/~spender/exploits/64bit_regleak.c) it.

Comment: I have discovered by trying to run old x86 assembly binaries (that's the reason I didn't just recompile into x64) that the registers aren't always preserved. Boo.

Comment: Is this still the case in current Linux? When I run [this code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HQQCnv7xZR/), which attempts to make a 32-bit getuid syscall, the number printed is -38, even though the man page for getuid indicates that it always succeeds.

Comment: @ameed: `-38` is `-ENOSYS`.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html explains that since Linux 2.4, you should use `getuid32`.  Apparently kernel support for the old `getuid` call number has been dropped, because I get the same thing on my Arch Linux desktop.  You'll see the same thing with the same `int 0x80` system call in 32-bit code where you can `strace` it and see glibc use `getuid32` and your code use `getuid`.  PS, you could just use `"=a"(ret)` like a normal person.  Yeah you do need clobbers on `r8..r11`, but not on any of the low 8 regs (with eax as an output operand)

Comment: Aha, I made the changes (changing the syscall number to $199 for `getuid32` and changing the constraints and clobbers) and it now prints my uid, as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible at all for `strace`/`ptrace()` to detect whether a syscall was made via `int 0x80` or `syscall`? There is an unanswered question on this: https://superuser.com/questions/834122/how-to-distinguish-syscalls-form-int-80h-when-using-ptrace